# How do I get the headers from a MockBackend with angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm having trouble checking the headers sent by my code from inside a unit test, using MockBackend.

I'm executing the following inside a test:

```
injectAsync([Http, XHRBackend], (http: Http, backend: MockBackend) => {
  return new Promise((pass, fail) => {
    var request: Request;

    backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => {
      request = c.request;
      c.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions()));
    })

    let req_headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer foo'});
    http.get('/', new ResponseOptions({headers: req_headers})).subscribe(
      () => {
        // I try to get the request headers here
        console.log(request.headers);
        pass();
      },
      fail
    )
  })
})
```

However, when I try to read back the headers, I'm getting an empty header set. The result of the log statement gives me `Headers{_headersMap: Map{}}`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, they are there but the headers property is a `Map` so you need to get it this way:

```
// All headers
for (var key of connection.request.headers.keys()) {
  console.log('- key = ' + key);
}

// Authorization header
var auth = connection.request.headers.get('Authorization');
console.log('auth = '+auth);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. Using the above, I get the output `'auth = null'`.

Comment: Really? I made it work on my side. Did you import the `Headers` class? `import {Http,Headers, ...} from 'angular2/http';`

Comment: Naw, not really :). It was a mistake on my part. Thanks for the help mate.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this plunk (file src/myservice.spec.ts lines 52-71);

```
  it('should do something',injectAsync([Http, XHRBackend], (http: Http, backend: MockBackend) => {
return new Promise((pass, fail) => {

  backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => {
    console.log(c.request.headers);// headers will be defined here
    //if you want this to pass, you have to do a little bit more with the response
    c.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions()));
  })
  //headers will need to be imported from 'angular2/http'
  let req_headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer foo'});
  //response options is not what you need to pass into http.get. you want to pass RequestOptions
  http.get('/', {headers: req_headers}).subscribe(
    () => {
      pass();
    },
    //fail needs to be called to fail.
    fail();
  )
})
```

}));

Comment: btw I don't think you need to injectAsync for this, I think mockBackend returns synchronously